# Trouble parsing this file in python

Tags: python, parsing

I'm parsing a file like this one in python :
1bgxt is the protein, sequence and secondary structure and phi angle is the type of information and the sequences are informations i want in a list with the coreponding protein. 
The fact that information about proteins are alternating cause me some trouble.
File exemple (it can have more than 2 proteins and more than 2 sequences information) :

```
P1;1bgxt
sequence
MRGMLPLFEPKGRVLLVDGHHLAYRTFHALKGLTTSRGEPVQAVYGFAKSLLKALKEDGDAVIVVFDAKAPSFRH*
P1;1xo1a
sequence
----------RRNLMIVDGTNLGFRFP--------------FASSYVSTIQSLAKSYSARTTIVLGDKG-KSVFR*
P1;1bgxt
secondary structure and phi angle
CPPCCCPPPCPCPCCCCCCCCHHHHCCCCPCCCCCCCPCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHCPCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC*
P1;1xo1a
secondary structure and phi angle
----------CCEEEEEEHHHHHCCCC--------------CHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCPEEEEEEECCCP-CCHHH*
```

And so on with more sequences.

I want to store information like this :

```
list = [
    ["1bgxt",
     "MRGMLPLFEPKGRVLLVDGHHLAYRTFHALKGLTTSRGEPVQAVYGFAKSLLKALKEDGDAVIVVFDAKAPSFRH*",
     CPPCCCPPPCPCPCCCCCCCCHHHHCCCCPCCCCCCCPCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHCPCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC*],
    ["1xo1a",
     "----------RRNLMIVDGTNLGFRFP--------------FASSYVSTIQSLAKSYSARTTIVLGDKG-KSVFR*",
     "----------CCEEEEEEHHHHHCCCC--------------CHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCPEEEEEEECCCP-CCHHH*"]
]
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What code have you written to try parsing this? Can you give more information about this file? Do all proteins have exactly one sequence and exactly one secondary structure and phi angle? Are there proteins that don't have both? Is the structure of this file always that predictable? (protein name / `sequence` keyword / sequence / etc.) followed by (protein name / `secondary structure` keyword / structure / etc.)

Comment: All proteins have one sequence and one secondary structure. They all have both (or the file is considered invalid). The file is always that predicable but he can have more structure types (but all proteins have all structure types)

Comment: `The file is always that predicable but he can have more structure types.` - does that mean there are other things that aren't `secondary structure and phi angle`? I'm trying to figure out whether or not you could get away with a parser that does 'bare minimum', or whether or not you need a lot more checks.

Comment: Yes but all protein have all information type and information types are always in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming you have a file that follows this rough structure:

```
P1;1bgxt
sequence
MRGMLPLFEPKGRVLLVDGHHLAYRTFHALKGLTTSRGEPVQAVYGFAKSLLKALKEDGDAVIVVFDAKAPSFRH*
P1;1xo1a
sequence
----------RRNLMIVDGTNLGFRFP--------------FASSYVSTIQSLAKSYSARTTIVLGDKG-KSVFR*
P1;1bgxt
secondary structure and phi angle
CPPCCCPPPCPCPCCCCCCCCHHHHCCCCPCCCCCCCPCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHCPCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC*
P1;1xo1a
secondary structure and phi angle
----------CCEEEEEEHHHHHCCCC--------------CHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCPEEEEEEECCCP-CCHHH*
```

The 'trick' to parsing this file is that you can just read the file by groups of 3 lines at a time, because the structure of the file is easily broken down to repeating cycles of:

```
Protein Name
Data Descriptor
Data
```

I'm making these **basic assumptions** because of what you have mentioned in comments:

- *Data Descriptor* is either **sequence** or something related to **structure**
- All proteins have a **sequence** and some type of **structure**
- All **sequence** data comes before **structure** data
- Files that have a line-count not divisible by 6 are bad files (because you need 6 lines total to represent each protein)

### Parsing into a `dict`

I would start off by saying that the structure you want in your original post is probably sub-optimal for parsing the data, and that you have data that neatly fits into an associative data structure like a `dict`.

Assume you have a file like above, called `sequences.txt`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import pprint

# This is adapted from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

proteins = {}
with open('sequences.txt') as datafile:

    # The following line reads the file as groups of 3 lines
    # I do this rather than read the entire file in one go because
    # you might have a lot of data in a file
    line_groups = grouper(datafile, 3)

    for block in line_groups:
        # I am adding variables here to make it clearer
        protein_name = block[0].strip()
        descriptor = block[1].strip()
        data = block[2].strip()

        if descriptor.lower() == 'sequence':
            # sequence is found, that means we haven't
            # seen this protein yet
            proteins[protein_name] = [protein_name, data]
        else:
            # This is some type of structure data, so just append to what
            # we've already seen
            try:
                protein = proteins[protein_name]
                protein.append(data)
            except KeyError:
                # Wait, how did we see a structure before a sequence?
                # This file is invalid

                raise # Or handle it however you want - exit, or discard data, etc.

pprint.pprint(proteins)
```

This will output a structure like this:

```
{'P1;1bgxt': ['P1;1bgxt',
              'MRGMLPLFEPKGRVLLVDGHHLAYRTFHALKGLTTSRGEPVQAVYGFAKSLLKALKEDGDAVIVVFDAKAPSFRH*',
              'CPPCCCPPPCPCPCCCCCCCCHHHHCCCCPCCCCCCCPCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHCPCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC*'],
 'P1;1xo1a': ['P1;1xo1a',
              '----------RRNLMIVDGTNLGFRFP--------------FASSYVSTIQSLAKSYSARTTIVLGDKG-KSVFR*',
              '----------CCEEEEEEHHHHHCCCC--------------CHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCPEEEEEEECCCP-CCHHH*']}
```

If you want to get the list of lists, you can just call `.values()` on `proteins`:

```
>> proteins.values()

[['P1;1bgxt',
  'MRGMLPLFEPKGRVLLVDGHHLAYRTFHALKGLTTSRGEPVQAVYGFAKSLLKALKEDGDAVIVVFDAKAPSFRH*',
  'CPPCCCPPPCPCPCCCCCCCCHHHHCCCCPCCCCCCCPCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHCPCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC*'],
 ['P1;1xo1a',
  '----------RRNLMIVDGTNLGFRFP--------------FASSYVSTIQSLAKSYSARTTIVLGDKG-KSVFR*',
  '----------CCEEEEEEHHHHHCCCC--------------CHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCPEEEEEEECCCP-CCHHH*']]
```

### Parsing into a `list` of `list` directly

This involves some different work if you didn't want to use a `dict` like in the last block of code, but you only have to change a couple of lines.

Note that given a large-enough data set, this version will likely take more time because as it is, it will scan the list every time you need to find a pre-existing protein to add structure data to an existing sublist (an `O(n)` operation), whereas in a dictionary, the lookup for a protein's data is typically `O(1)`. Though what might work for you may differ depending on what you're using the data for, but I digress.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import pprint

# This is adapted from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

proteins = []
with open('sequences.txt') as datafile:

    # The following line reads the file as groups of 3 lines
    # I do this rather than read the entire file in one go because
    # you might have a lot of data in a file
    line_groups = grouper(datafile, 3)

    for block in line_groups:
        # I am adding variables here to make it clearer
        protein_name = block[0].strip()
        descriptor = block[1].strip()
        data = block[2].strip()

        if descriptor.lower() == 'sequence':
            # sequence is found, that means we haven't
            # seen this protein yet
            proteins.append([protein_name, data])
        else:
            # This is some type of structure data, so just append to what
            # we've already seen

            # find the item in the list that contains this protein
            try:
                protein = next(x for x in proteins if x[0] == protein_name)
                protein.append(data)
            except StopIteration:
                # Hm, we couldn't find a sublist that has this protein name
                raise

pprint.pprint(proteins)
```

This will output:

```
>> pprint.pprint(proteins)
[['P1;1bgxt',
  'MRGMLPLFEPKGRVLLVDGHHLAYRTFHALKGLTTSRGEPVQAVYGFAKSLLKALKEDGDAVIVVFDAKAPSFRH*',
  'CPPCCCPPPCPCPCCCCCCCCHHHHCCCCPCCCCCCCPCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHCPCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC*'],
 ['P1;1xo1a',
  '----------RRNLMIVDGTNLGFRFP--------------FASSYVSTIQSLAKSYSARTTIVLGDKG-KSVFR*',
  '----------CCEEEEEEHHHHHCCCC--------------CHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCPEEEEEEECCCP-CCHHH*']]
```

Note that I don't do anything like rigorous error checking, and I tried to use more demonstrative code than would likely be done in idiomatic code for clarity. I also didn't try to go too fancy with using stuff like classes to store data, or using tuples or `namedtuple` to store all the relevant data because that would require more preprocessing of the file for perhaps minimal gain in usefulness (tuples are immutable in Python so I can't just modify a tuple without just creating a new one).